# Closing brace to terminate statement

Tags: ruby

I was trying to explore the various ways to end or terminate a statement in ruby. I know of semicolon and new line. Are there other possible ways? And does new line always terminate the statement? Also, what is a good programming practice to follow?

Comment: check out Githubs style guide: https://github.com/styleguide/ruby

Comment: Write your code for readability. There are seldom good reasons to write terse code these days, because the interpreters are smarter than the BASIC interpreters of old. Semicolons and/or terse code are seldom needed in Ruby, whereas readable code is always needed.

Comment: Your title does not match the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there other possible ways?

Yes. for example, in a conditional expression like this:

```
if foo then bar else baz end
```

The condition is terminated by the `then` keyword, the then-branch is terminated by the `else` keyword, and the else-branch is terminated by the `end` keyword.

> And does new line always terminate the statement?

No. There are many cases where Ruby can tell that an expression isn't finished yet, and in that case, a newline will not terminate the expression.

Some examples are

- binary infix operators without their right operand:

  ```
  23 + 
    42

  foo = 
    42
  ```
- A unary prefix operator missing its operand:

  ```
  -
    42

  !
    false
  ```

  Here's a fun little piece of code using that:

  ```
  foo++
  bar

  # same as
  foo + +bar

  # same as
  foo.+(bar.+@)
  ```
- An unclosed list:

  ```
  puts(23, 
    42)

  foo, 
    bar = 23, 
      42

  [23, 
    42]

  {foo: 23, 
    bar: 42}

  def foo(bar, 
    baz) end
  ```
- An unclosed literal:

  ```
  [
    23, 42
  ]

  {
    foo: 23, bar: 42
  }

  'foo
  bar'

  "foo
  bar"

  %w!
    hello
    world
  !
  ```
- Missing values in a `Hash` literal:

  ```
  { :foo => 
    :bar, baz: 
    :quux }
  ```
- A message send missing the message to send:

  ```
  23.
    to_s
  ```
- Even this is supported:

  ```
  23
    .to_s
  ```
- Escaping a newline will also not make it terminate the expression:

  ```
  "foo" \
    "bar"
  ```

There's probably a couple of others I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon is not a good practice in Ruby.The newline is enough. Use semicolon to separate commands only if it shortens the code without loosing human readability. For example, you may use the semicolon:

```
posx = 0.0; posy = 0.0; posz = 0.0
```

instead of:

```
posx = 0.0
posy = 0.0
posz = 0.0
```

Comment: You're right. My snippet was just an example, maybe not good enough. But is shows that you don't need use semicolons at all ;)

Comment: In my coding and in our team, I seldom use or recommend the use of semicolons. In Ruby they're just not that necessary and are generally avoided. If this was Perl or C it'd definitely be a different case as they're semicolon crazy.